# Mastery-based grading for Theory of Computation

Tags: fl.formal-languages, automata-theory, teaching

I would be interested to learn of anyone's experience using mastery-based (or "mastery-level") grading in a *Theory of Computation* course.
Usually this requires—at a minimum— a detailed taxonomy of competencies, and what it means to 
demonstrate mastery of each competency.